# Is it possible to allow users to change the font of a document in Microsoft Word but not the content?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2016

I am using Microsoft Word 2016 on Windows 8.1.

I would like to lock the text of a document against editing, but allow users to change the font to whatever they want (or pre-set styles if 'anything they want' isn't possible), so they can pick whatever is most readable for them.

I can see that Restricted Editing has some options for styles, but I can't see an easy way to allow changing of styles but not content.

Comment: Looks like this is not possible in MS word 2016

Comment: Check if this article is helpful: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/restrict-or-permit-formatting-changes-69ca7857-db43-4785-9e14-7735db6d79bb#bm1

Answer (score 0):

That would require a macro either embedded in the document or in an attached template. The macro would control what was allowed to be done.